# There is 429 error when request to Google People API

Tags: google-people-api

I'm having error with 429 code when I request to Google People API. Message: "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)" But quota wasn't exceeded, there was 5-10 requests per day at all during last 6 months.
After 30th of March all my requests returned with error 429.
Does anybody met this problem?